# Where in the Solr source code does Solr initially parse the URL

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, solr, lucene

Suppose I make a query like http://hostname.com:9000/solr/main0/select?.......

My query has some non-ASCII characters encoded like `%C2%B1` (±). Sometime before it reaches my custom plugin, the character just gets transformed to `?`. I am not sure where this is happening, but I am wondering exactly which solr source file is responsible for doing the initial parsing of the URL. From there, I can probably pinpoint the problem to exactly where it goes wrong through a series of debug statements.

I am using solr 4.10.2

I assumed [SearchHandler.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/4.10.2/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/component/SearchHandler.java) would be the place, but `handleRequestBody` takes a `SolrQueryRequest` object, and I am having a lot of trouble pinpointing where this object is originally populated.

Comment: URLs are parsed and processed by the embedded jetty server first - it might be wrong even before Solr gets the value.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for that insight. I will investigate that as well.